# How to get the max value for key in nested dictionary of list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I wanted to print a dictionary with key and its max value by searching value in its key .

```
Input
dict_1 = {
    0: [1], 
    1: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 16, 18], 
    12: [13, 14, 15], 
    14: [37],
    16: [17], 
    18: [19], 
    19: [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 37, 45], 
    29: [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36], 
    37: [38, 39, 40, 41, 42], 
    42: [43, 44], 
    45: [46]
}

Expected Output
dict_2 = {0: 46, 1: 46, 12: 44, 14:44, 16: 17, 18: 46, 19: 46, 29: 36, 37: 44, 42: 44, 45: 46}
```

For example key 0 has value 1 and this value is 2nd key of my dictionary and this key has value 18 which is also a key in the dictionary and this key 18 has value 19 which is again a key with max value as 45 and it is also a key with value 46 and therefor the max value for key 0 is 46

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dict_1 = {0: [1], 
1: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 16, 18], 
12: [13, 14, 15], 
14: [37],
16: [17], 
18: [19], 
19: [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 37, 45], 
29: [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36], 
37: [38, 39, 40, 41, 42], 
42: [43, 44], 
45: [46]}

d={}

for key,value in dict_1.items():
    val=[i for i in value if i in dict_1]
    if val:
        val=max(val)
        while val in dict_1:
            val=max(dict_1[val])
        new_val=val
    else:
        new_val=max(value)
    d[key]=new_val

print(d) # {0: 46, 1: 46, 12: 44, 14: 44, 16: 17, 18: 46, 19: 46, 29: 36, 37: 44, 42: 44, 45: 46}
```

Comment: for key 12 the value expected is 44 and not 15

Comment: can you explain how that is possible?

Comment: for key 12 we have 3 values namely 13,14,15 and  value 14 is a key with value 37 and 37 is also a key with value 42 and 42 is a key with  value 44 which is maximum as compared to the value 15

Comment: you specified max value, how is 14 a max value when you have 15?

Comment: @vinodetrx Your question is not clear then. You didn't specified that you need the maximum value which at the same time needs to be a key of the dictionary.

Comment: I wanted max value based on all possible combinations

Comment: @K.Railis: Regret for the inconvenience in understanding my question.....I wanted maximum value based on all possible combinations

Comment: Why is there no key `14` in "Expected Output"? When all other keys from input are present

Comment: I forgot to add key 14 sorry ...in the output there is one more element {14: 44}

Comment: check the edited code, I am not sure what you meant by "all possible combinations" though

Answer (score 0):

dict_1 =
{

```
0: [1],
1: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 16, 18],
12: [13, 14, 15],
14: [37],
16: [17],
18: [19],
19: [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 37, 45],
29: [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36],
37: [38, 39, 40, 41, 42],
42: [43, 44],
45: [46]
```

}

def maxv(d, k):

```
if k not in d.keys():
    return k
else:
    m = max(d[k])
    return maxv(d, m)
```

def create_dict(dic):

```
d = {}
for key in dic.keys():
    d[key] = maxv(dic, key)
return d
```

print(create_dict(dict_1))